# What happens if the Inherits attribute is removed from the @Page directive?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I don't know what happened with my project, but since I reinstalled my pc with Windows 8, the website doesn't build...

My @Page directives look summing like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeBehind="Register.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Register" %>
```

The codebehind for this page looks like this:

```
Partial Class _Register
    Inherits MobilePage

    ' subs go here (don't think they're important for the question)

End Class
```

With this set up this way, I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load type '_Register'.

Removing the Inherits attribute fixes this error, but what else does it do in terms of the page's functionality?

Comment: It means that for some reason the project can't load the `_Register` class..most likely you're missing some DLLs or a class file has been corrupted on your disk

Comment: Okay but I still don't understand what happens if I remove the attribute...